How to make ENT:Touch only detect touches from a certain entity [GLua]
I cannot figure out how to make ENT:Touch only detect when touching a specific entity instead of detecting anything and everything touching it. It probably has something to do with the argument but nothing I've tried has worked
current code (useless)
function ENT:Touch(entity)      
    EmitSound( Sound ("buttons/lightswitch2.wav" ), self:GetPos(), 1, CHAN_AUTO, 1, 75, 0, 100)
    self:Remove()
    end

I've tried making the argument the entity name, Using getclass in an if statement (to see if I can do if getclass comes back as the entity run the code) but neither of these or any variations of them have worked.

GetClass is the way to do it! How you tried to use it?

Yes I have but I have no clue how to do anything like "if getclass()= entity then run code" and when I try it just gives errors (also I already said this in the original post)
